# Breaking a c string into tokens through strtok

Tags: c, strtok

In the following piece of code, i see that after breaking `userHostPairs` in tokens and assigning to itself doesn't work.
After breaking into tokens i print `userHostPairs` in loop and in the same loop i also print 0th element always through `printf("0Printing after strtok = %s",userHostPairs[0]);` which prints weird values(most probably the last fetched value).

```
FILE* fp;        
char  line[100];        
char* userHostPairs[100];

fp = fopen("somefile", "r");

//READING THE FILE LINE BY LINE. WORKS FINE  
        int count =0;
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL ) {
                userHostPairs[count]=malloc(MAX_LINE_SIZE);
                strcpy(userHostPairs[count],line);
                count++;
        }

///PROBLEMATIC CODE////////////////////

        for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
                char temp[100];
                strcpy(temp,userHostPairs[i]);

                userHostPairs[i] = strtok(temp,"@");
                userHostPairs[i] = strtok(NULL,"@");
                printf("Printing after strtok = %s",userHostPairs[i]);
                printf("0Printing after strtok = %s",userHostPairs[0]); //This 0th element is always some random(or last) value fetched.
        }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Printing in strtok = 10.238.178.136
0Printing in strtok = 10.238.178.136
Printing in strtok = 10.238.152.101
0Printing in strtok = 10.238.152.101
Printing in strtok = eaasrt
0Printing in strtok = eaasrt
Printing in strtok = eaasrt7
0Printing in strtok = aasrt7
```

Comment: The code you’ve posted contains a lot of irrelevant logic. It would be good if you could reduce the code to the essential, and remove everything that’s not required to reproduce the problem. In particular this includes file reading.

Comment: ... in other words, read this: how to privide a [mcve]

Comment: @KonradRudolph I reduced the code

Comment: This line `userHostPairs[i] = strtok(temp,"@");` doesn't look right.  Shouldn't you be doing a strcpy instead of an assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> prints weird values(most probably the last fetched value).

this is because of several errors in your code

```
            char temp[100];

            userHostPairs[i] = strtok(temp,"@");
            userHostPairs[i] = strtok(NULL,"@");
```

the assignments are not what you want for 3 reasons :

- you replace the *mallocd* block (rather than probably to *strcpy* in it), so you create a memory leak
- you assign two times the same entry in *userHostPairs*, so the first result of *strtok* is lost
- *strtok* returns pointers in *temp* and you modify *temps* the next loop so the previous results are broken

---

Of course when you will go out of the scope of *temp* any uses to pointer saved in *userHostPairs*  will have an undefined behavior, but this is not the reason of the result you see because your writes are in the scope of *temp*

---

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t read(size_t sz, char *a1[sz], char * a2[sz])
{
  FILE* fp = fopen("f", "r");

  if (fp == 0)
    return 0;

  char line[50];        
  size_t rank;

  for (rank = 0; rank != sz; ++rank) {
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) == NULL)
      break;

    char * p1, * p2;

    if (((p1 = strtok(line, "@")) == NULL) ||
        ((p2 = strtok(NULL, "@\n")) == NULL))
      break;

    a1[rank] = malloc(strlen(p1) + 1);
    strcpy(a1[rank], p1);

    a2[rank] = malloc(strlen(p2) + 1);
    strcpy(a2[rank], p2);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return rank;
}

#define N 50

int main()
{
  char * a1[N];
  char * a2[N];
  size_t n = read(N, a1, a2);

  for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    printf("'%s' / '%s'\n", a1[i], a2[i]);

  /* ... */

  /* free resources */
  for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    free(a1[i]);
    free(a2[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note if you have *strdup* you can replace

```
    a1[rank] = malloc(strlen(p1) + 1);
    strcpy(a1[rank], p1);

    a2[rank] = malloc(strlen(p2) + 1);
    strcpy(a2[rank], p2);
```

by

```
    a1[rank] = strsup(p1);
    a2[rank] = strdup(p2);
```

Having the file *f* containing :

```
aze@qsd@
wxc@iop
iop@jkl
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'aze' / 'qsd'
'wxc' / 'iop'
'iop' / 'jkl'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==6244== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6244== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6244== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6244== Command: ./a.out
==6244== 
'aze' / 'qsd'
'wxc' / 'iop'
'iop' / 'jkl'
==6244== 
==6244== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6244==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6244==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 5,496 bytes allocated
==6244== 
==6244== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6244== 
==6244== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6244== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
```

If you do not want to limit the number of elements in the arrays you can use *malloc* then *realloc* for the arrays :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t read(char *** a1, char *** a2)
{
  *a1 = malloc(0);
  *a2 = malloc(0);

  FILE* fp = fopen("f", "r");

  if (fp == 0)
    return 0;

  char line[50];        
  size_t rank = 0;

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
    char * p1, * p2;

    if (((p1 = strtok(line, "@")) == NULL) ||
        ((p2 = strtok(NULL, "@\n")) == NULL))
      break;

    *a1 = realloc(*a1, (rank+1) * sizeof(char *));
    (*a1)[rank] = malloc(strlen(p1) + 1);
    strcpy((*a1)[rank], p1);

    *a2 = realloc(*a2, (rank+1) * sizeof(char *));
    (*a2)[rank] = malloc(strlen(p2) + 1);
    strcpy((*a2)[rank], p2);

    rank += 1;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return rank;
}

int main()
{
  char ** a1;
  char ** a2;
  size_t n = read(&a1, &a2);

  for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    printf("'%s' / '%s'\n", a1[i], a2[i]);

  /* ... */

  /* free resources */
  for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    free(a1[i]);
    free(a2[i]);
  }
  free(a1);
  free(a2);

  return 0;
}
```

With the same file *f* , compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall st.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'aze' / 'qsd'
'wxc' / 'iop'
'iop' / 'jkl'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==6423== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6423== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6423== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6423== Command: ./a.out
==6423== 
'aze' / 'qsd'
'wxc' / 'iop'
'iop' / 'jkl'
==6423== 
==6423== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6423==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6423==   total heap usage: 17 allocs, 17 frees, 5,544 bytes allocated
==6423== 
==6423== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6423== 
==6423== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6423== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Can you explain the first point about "you replace the mallocd block" please?

Comment: @anurag86 You have memory leaks because of overwriting `userHostPairs[i]` with `strtok` return.

Comment: @anurag86 you assign  `userHostPairs[i]` so the previous value in `userHostPairs[i]` is lost and you have a memory leak

Comment: @bruno lso by 3rd point - temp wont be out of scope till for loop finishes. Moreover am i not assigning the temp value to userHostPair whose  scope isnt limited to loop?

Comment: Also, an offtrack question - If i declare `char* (*oActualList)[100] = &userHostPairs;` , is it wrong to expect (*oActual)[i] to print same values as userHostPairs[i] holds?

Comment: @anurag86 _strtok_ returns an address pointing **inside** _temp_, so out of the loop the memorized address are invalid.

Comment: @anurag86 and yes `&(*oActualList)[i] == &userHostPairs[i]`, but what that changes something about your problem ?

Comment: Well the above piece of code is a function which looks like `void getActualList(char* (*oActualList)[100])` and in main() i have `char* actualList[100]; getActualList(&actualList);` , but when coming back to main, i cant printf the results in `actualList`
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194452/discussion-between-anurag86-and-bruno).

Comment: @anurag86 I edited my answer to add two proposal, the first one closer to your where the receiver arrays have a limited size, the second without limiting/supposing how much elements will be read

Comment: thnx bruno. it worked for me well. However with valgrind i see weird error on strcpy with my program. But valgrind has no issues after replacing the two lines with strdup  `==11955==    at 0x4C2AAD0: strcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==11955==    by 0x400C1D: getActualList (anurag.c:95)
==11955==    by 0x400D34: main (anurag.c:115)
==11955==  Address 0x51f4c48 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==11955==    at 0x4C27BE3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==11955==    by 0x400BF1: getActualList (anurag.c:94)
==11955==    by 0x400D34: main (anurag.c:115)
`

Comment: @anurag86 if ok with _strdup_ but nok with _strcpy_ and considering the message of _valgrind_ that probably means you wrongly `malloc(strlen(xx))` rather than `malloc(strlen(xx) + 1 )`